# Insert HTML via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, css-position

I'm attempting to insert a 'Free Draw Box' into my webpage only using JavaScript. I've been able to get my 'Free Draw Box Script' to work on the page with the HTML present, but I would like to accomplish this by inserting the HTML via JavaScript instead. I've included a snippet of my entire code, however, I believe that the code in question is towards the bottom- commented as 'Insert HTML.' Where is my mistake?

```html
<html>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    /*Free Draw Box Script*/
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;
    
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
    
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }
    
    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the Signature?");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    function save() {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }
    
    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    
            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }

    /*Insert HTML*/
    document.body.innerHTML += '
        <body onload="init()">
            <canvas id="can" width="800" height="200" 
            style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:1px solid;">
            </canvas>

            <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;
            left:52%;" style="display:none;">
            <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" 
            onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;
            left:15%;">
        </body>
    ';

    </script>

    <body>
        <p></p>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: '/" quoted string doesn't support multiple line, you need to use ` in this case.

Comment: The best way to `insert HTML` using javascript is to use jQuery within Javascript, You include Jquery just like any other .js file. Please see url: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-jquery#setting-up-jquery

Comment: jQuery is absolutely not necessary to insert HTML using JavaScript. JavaScript has plenty of built-in, widely-supported functionality to do this without any external libraries or frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend putting in html as such using JS, but well here is the fix:

1. Use [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the html string.
2. Also use `outerHTML` to put in the `body` element from the string too.

See demo below:

```js
var canvas,ctx,flag=!1,prevX=0,currX=0,prevY=0,currY=0,dot_flag=!1;var x="black",y=2;function init(){canvas=document.getElementById('can');ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");w=canvas.width;h=canvas.height;canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){findxy('move',e)},!1);canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){findxy('down',e)},!1);canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){findxy('up',e)},!1);canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){findxy('out',e)},!1)}
function draw(){ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(prevX,prevY);ctx.lineTo(currX,currY);ctx.strokeStyle=x;ctx.lineWidth=y;ctx.stroke();ctx.closePath()}
function erase(){var m=confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the Signature?");if(m){ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display="none"}}
function save(){document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border="2px solid";var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL();document.getElementById("canvasimg").src=dataURL;document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display="inline"}
function findxy(res,e){if(res=='down'){prevX=currX;prevY=currY;currX=e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;currY=e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;flag=!0;dot_flag=!0;if(dot_flag){ctx.beginPath();ctx.fillStyle=x;ctx.fillRect(currX,currY,2,2);ctx.closePath();dot_flag=!1}}
if(res=='up'||res=="out"){flag=!1}
if(res=='move'){if(flag){prevX=currX;prevY=currY;currX=e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;currY=e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop;draw()}}}

/*Insert HTML*/
document.body.outerHTML += `<body onload="init()">
            <canvas id="can" width="800" height="200" 
  style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:1px solid;">
            </canvas>
            <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;
            left:52%;" style="display:none;">
            <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" 
            onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;
            left:15%;">
        </body>`;
```

Comment: kukkuz, the snippet you provided above worked like a charm! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    /*Free Draw Box Script*/
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;
    
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
    
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }
    
    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the Signature?");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    function save() {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }
    
    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    
            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }

    /*Insert HTML*/
    document.body.innerHTML += `
        <body onload="init()">
            <canvas id="can" width="800" height="200" 
            style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:1px solid;">
            </canvas>

            <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;
            left:52%;" style="display:none;">
            <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" 
            onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;
            left:15%;">
        </body>
    `;

    </script>

    <body>
        <p></p>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a body into the body wont work, and its onload function does not get called. Instead, create the DOM directly using js, then add it to the page. So to create the canvas you would do:

```
var can = document.createElement("canvas");
can.width = 800;
can.height = 200;
document.body.appendChild(can);

//you can use it directly
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
```